# Xamarin.Forms VoiceOver in two vertical stacks

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, voiceover

I do have one hozitontal StackLayout that contains two vertical StackLayouts. When I turn on VoiceOver it reads by rows not by stacks. Is there any solution? I also tried that in Grid but problem was same... ty

Comment: Which control do you use in the StackLayout? The VoiceOver will read depending on control, I'm confused about " by rows not by stacks"?

Comment: I have my own controls that are usually combination of Labels and Image (icon). "by rows not stacks" I mean that it doesnt read whole vertical stack and than the other one, but it reads first row in first vertical, then first row ind second vertical... I need force it somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using

```
AutomationProperties.SetIsInAccessibleTree(myStackLayout, true);
AutomationProperties.SetName(myStackLayout, Title + " " + Value + " " + Unit);
```

it reads well whole control at once

source: https://blog.xamarin.com/accessbility-xamarin-forms/